# Deleting entities vs updating relationship

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I have an application that I am building to deploy on Google App Engine, and I have the entity relationship as defined below (simplified)

```
public class League {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="league")
  private List<Team> teams;
}

public class Team {
  @ManyToOne
  private League league;
}
```

My question is, when I want to delete a team, can I simply use the entity manager remove() method within a transaction:

```
Team teamToDelete = em.find(Team.class, teamId);
em.remove(teamToDelete);
```

, or do I have to update both sides of the relationship manually by updating the List of Teams for the League and removing the team, and then set the League to null for the Team?

Answer (score 0):

Entities that belong to the same entity group are physically stored together, so you can just delete the child entity (Team) and the League entity will be impacted in the datastore.

From a pure java standpoint, if you have a a league object instance that referenced the team you just deleted in the datastore, you might have to "refresh" that object though.

Comment: What do you mean by the same entity group?

Comment: The GAE datastore persists your JPA entity and its owned "relationships" as an entity group. The top object of the hierarchy (here : `League`) is called the root entity, and each object referenced in a `OneToMany` collection (here : `Team`) is a child entity. Think of it as a Tree data structure.

Comment: Ok, so the delete only works because this is deployed on GAE, correct? If I was using Hibernates implementation, would I have to manually update both sides of the relationship?